# use codepen example in wordpress not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

i want use social share button for my wordpress. [i want this](https://codepen.io/envira/pen/qzDup)

i add html css and js but it's not work. i think js not work , how i know js code work ? is it need change js code ?

and because the function file coded i couldn't use function.php file

*i don't need plugin or sample social code that without js, thanks*

HTML

```
<div class='sbutton'>
  <span>Share</span>
  <ul class='smenu'>
    <li class="facebook"><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
    <li class="twitter"><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
    <li class="googleplus"><a href="">Google +</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sbutton {
  background-color: #E04006;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #9C4015;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}

.sbutton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.smenu {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  left: -20px;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.smenu:after {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
  top: -7px;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}

.smenu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 100px;
}

.smenu li:hover {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.smenu .facebook:hover {
  background-color: #4C66A4;
  color: #FFF !important;
}

.smenu .twitter:hover {
  background-color: #019AD2;
  color: #FFF !important;
}

.smenu .googleplus:hover {
  background-color: #D73D32;
  color: #FFF !important;
}

.smenu li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.smenu li a {
  color: #E04006;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.smenu li:hover a {
  color:#fff !important;
}

.smenu.share {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 45px;
}
```

JS

```
$('.sbutton').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.smenu').toggleClass('share');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load [JQuery](https://jquery.com/). The javascript you posted makes use of JQuery, so you need to load JQuery before any of your javascript is executed (In fact the Codepen you linked to also has JQuery enabled in its settings). One way to load JQuery is to place

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
```

in your HTML *before* the `<script>` tag containing your Javascript.

This loads JQuery from a CDN (in this case, Google's CDN). You can find  a list of CDNs in the [Download section of the JQuery site](https://jquery.com/download/#other-cdns).

Alternatively, from the JQuery site, you can download the JQuery file and host it yourself - then you simply link to it like any other Javascript file (from a `<script>` tag) *before* your Javascript code/file.

Regardless of how you do it, JQuery must be included **before** your own Javascript code.